# the scroll bar is hidden behind the keyboard

Tags: iphone, uitableview, keyboard, scrollbar, iphone-softkeyboard

I have a `UITableViewController` with a search bar. When I touch the screen to start the search, I hide the `UINavigationBar` and show the scope bar search to optimize the space.

For the TableView not hide behind the keyboard and search bar, I add header and footer to the table with their respective heights.

Everything working correctly. But the scroll bar is still hiding behind the search bar and keyboard.

Any suggestions to solve this or some other way to do this whole mechanism?

Comment: You need to shorten the table view by the heigh of the keyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resize the table view's frame by subtracting the height of the keyboard.

Comment: I was trying this, but wrongly. Now used "setFrame:CGRectMake" and it worked correctly. Thank you!